# "echo -n" works fine when executing script with bash, but not with sh

Tags: macos, bash, echo

How come `sh UsersInput.sh` gives a different output compared to `bash UsersInput.sh`?

My script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter: ";
read usersinput;
echo "You entered, \"$usersinput\"";
```

**bash**

```
localhost:Bash henry$ bash UsersInput.sh 
Enter: input
You entered, "input"
```

**sh**

```
localhost:Bash henry$ sh UsersInput.sh
-n Enter: 
input
You entered, "input"
```

How come `-n` behaves properly with the first, but not with the second? What's the reason for this and is there a workaround?

Comment: which shell is your "sh"? What does /bin/sh point to? For maximum portability, use printf with no newline: `printf "Enter: "`

Comment: @glennjackman I will start using that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man echo`:

> Some shells may provide a builtin echo command which is similar or identical to this utility.  Most notably, the builtin echo in sh(1) does not accept the -n option.  Consult the builtin(1) manual page.

In bash, the Bourne-again shell, `echo` accepts the `-n` option whereas in sh, the Bourne shell, `echo` does not, so it simply echos everything you wrote, including the -n.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will start using `printf` as glenn suggested.

Comment: /bin/sh is not a Bourne shell on OS X. It is a POSIX-conformant version of bash. The /bin/sh and /bin/bash binaries are almost identical, but most of the differences (including the behavior of echo) depend on the name the shell is invoked with.

Answer (score 2):

/bin/sh is a version of bash (not a Bourne shell) on OS X. It has POSIX mode enabled and has a [few other changes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89311/are-bash-bourne-and-korn-shells-compiled-into-one-binary-in-osx/89327#89327) as well. One of them is that the xpg_echo shell option is enabled by default so that the builtin echo conforms to POSIX.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/echo.html:

> Implementations shall not support any options

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode:

> 44. When the xpg_echo option is enabled, Bash does not attempt to interpret any arguments to echo as options. Each argument is displayed, after escape characters are converted.
>
> [...]
>
> As noted above, Bash requires the xpg_echo option to be enabled for the echo builtin to be fully conformant.

You can unset xpg_echo, use /bin/echo, or preferably just use printf:

```
sh -c 'shopt -u xpg_echo; echo -n aa'
sh -c '/bin/echo -n aa'
sh -c 'printf %s aa'
```