# Create a npm command to create a file with content but without new line at the end

Tags: node.js, linux, macos, echo, package.json

I'm trying to use `echo -n` command to write some content to a file without a new line in node's package.json e.g

```
start: "echo -n hello > my.file"
```

When I run `npm start`, instead of `hello` without a new line, it creates `-n hello` in `my.file`. However it runs correctly in my Terminal(I'm on Mac).

Comment: Just trying to find an easy and quick way to create a file with no new line at the end. If there are other tools can do it, it's more than welcome.

Comment: Why not use your terminal directly instead of using Node.js?

Comment: @tobias, I'm combining with other commands with the newly created file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending of your context, you can use `printf` instead of `echo`, which does not append a `\n` char automatically.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58310/difference-between-printf-and-echo-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

This is due to NPM running scripts with the `sh(1)` shell, which does not accept the `-n` option. One way of solving this would be to set NPM to use Bash:

```sh
npm config set script-shell "/bin/bash"
```

> **Documentation for `echo` command**
>
> Some shells may provide a builtin echo command which is similar or identical to this utility.  Most notably, the builtin echo in sh(1) does not accept the -n option.  Consult the builtin(1) manual page.

> **[Documentation for NPM run-scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script)**
>
> The actual shell your script is run within is platform dependent. By default, on Unix-like systems it is the /bin/sh command, on Windows it is the cmd.exe. The actual shell referred to by /bin/sh also depends on the system. As of npm@5.1.0 you can customize the shell with the script-shell configuration.

Here's also a related StackOverflow answer: ["echo -n" works fine when executing script with bash, but not with sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865587/echo-n-works-fine-when-executing-script-with-bash-but-not-with-sh)

Comment: I ended up with `printf` command. However your answer also provides very valuable information to me.  Thanks